# Assign a single Option key to launch Mission Control

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

I want to assign an Option key to launch Mission Control. Is there a way to do it?

When I choose System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Mission Control > double click at Mission Control — it doesn't understand a single Option key hit.

Comment: Not surprising, given that this is almost always not what the user intends. Is there a particular reason you need this?

Comment: I achieved something similar using KeyboardRemap4Macbook to launch exposé with the right option key. Not sure if it works on Macs of if you have a Mac or a Macbook(Pro), or if it's been updated to work with Mission Control.

Comment: Daniel, I want to have a shortcut which doesn't require to look at the keyboard. I've changed the default F9 to F1, but still, the Option key is much simpler for my fingers to find it...  it's some kind of WASD.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very bad plan! How will you force quit applications? (<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>escape</kbd>)

Comment: **Force quit applications:** hold `option`, hold `command`, hold `escape`, release `escape`, release `command`, release `option`.

**Launch Mission Control:** press `option`, release `option`.

— These 2 shortcuts do not intersect.